# Pure CSS Slider with Autoplay

Tags: animation, slider, autoplay

how can I add more buttons(+3) to pure css slider from this site : http://cssslider.com/

I try to change .css files and html but something goes wrong ;/ 
Please help me add more working buttons, or if you could explain how to make radio-imput checked/unchecked with css animation

Comment: What do you mean more buttons(+3)?

Comment: There is 3 buttons in slider already, and i try add +3, second question : how to achieve effect : autoplay, like in this slider, what part of code is responsible for that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you download the slider software? Download and install the slider softwar. Now run software . You will see a window like [image]

Now click Add images. Add as many images as you need. If you add 6 images then 6 button will be create. For auto play click advance option. I hope you can do that. It last click Save HTML.

Comment: yes, i try this method and in the end you need to register and buy all created html for >50$ ... well, i can create similar slider with pure css, but what i need,is answer : how to jump from one checked input to another via css ,sorry for my lang. ;/